# How to sum a multiindexed pandas series based on changes in boolean column from true to false?

Tags: aggregation, multi-index, finance, quantitative-finance

I want to count the number of round trip (day trader) transactions in a set of stock trading transactions held in a pandas dataframe. My data originally has 3 columns: ['ticker', 'tradeDate', 'quantity']. I want to aggregate quantity based on the total positive quantity values.

My input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tradeDate':["12/28/2020", "12/28/2020", "12/28/2020", "12/28/2020", "12/28/2020", "12/28/2020", "12/28/2020", "12/28/2020", "12/27/2020", "12/27/2020", "12/27/2020", "12/27/2020", "12/27/2020", "12/27/2020", "12/27/2020"],
    'ticker':["A2", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A1", "A2", "A1", "A2", "A1"],
    'quantity':[-3, -2, 1, 3, 1, -1, 1, -2, 1, -5, -4, 5, 2, 1, 2]
    },columns=['tradeDate','ticker', 'quantity'])
```

| # | tradeDate | ticker | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12/28/2020 | A2 | -3 |
| 1 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | -2 |
| 2 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | 1 |
| 3 | 12/28/2020 | A2 | 3 |
| 4 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | 1 |
| 5 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | -1 |
| 6 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | 1 |
| 7 | 12/28/2020 | A2 | -2 |
| 8 | 12/27/2020 | A2 | 1 |
| 9 | 12/27/2020 | A2 | -5 |
| 10 | 12/27/2020 | A1 | -4 |
| 11 | 12/27/2020 | A2 | 5 |
| 12 | 12/27/2020 | A1 | 2 |
| 13 | 12/27/2020 | A2 | 1 |
| 14 | 12/27/2020 | A1 | 2 |

Note that index 7 is sold from long term holding and excluded from output.
Note that index 8 is purchased for long term holding and excluded from output.
Note that index 13 is purchased for long term holding and excluded from output.

My expected output:
roundTripCount = 5

My expected output df:

| # | tradeDate | ticker | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12/28/2020 | A2 | -3 |
| 1 | 12/28/2020 | A2 | 3 |
| 2 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | -2 |
| 3 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | 2 |
| 4 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | -1 |
| 5 | 12/28/2020 | A1 | 1 |
| 6 | 12/27/2020 | A2 | -5 |
| 7 | 12/27/2020 | A2 | 5 |
| 8 | 12/27/2020 | A1 | -4 |
| 9 | 12/27/2020 | A1 | 4 |

I have read through this question and the linked dupes, and it doesn't quite answer how to go about this.
[Counting the amount of times a boolean goes from True to False in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219948/counting-the-amount-of-times-a-boolean-goes-from-true-to-false-in-a-column)

I have tried making a column "q_bool" that is True if the quantity is > 0 and then used a slice by the ticker to check for changes in the q_bool, but it throws errors when including dates.

My current working solution is:

```py
    df['q_bool'] = (df['quantity'] > 0)
    ticker_set = set(df['ticker'])
    running_round_trips_counted = 0
    for ticker in ticker_set:
        ticker_mask = (df['ticker'] == ticker)
        temp_df_slice = df[ticker_mask]
        date_set = set(temp_df_slice['tradeDate'])
        for d in date_set:
            d_mask = (temp_df_slice['tradeDate'] == d)
            d_temp_df_slice = temp_df_slice[d_mask]
            d_temp_df_slice = d_temp_df_slice.groupby([d_temp_df_slice['q_bool'].ne(df['q_bool'].shift()).cumsum(), 'q_bool']).size()
            half_of_transactions = math.trunc(len(d_temp_df_slice)/2)
            running_round_trips_counted = running_round_trips_counted + half_of_transactions

    print(running_round_trips_counted)
```

the output is 6 round trips.

The above code feels hacky and hard to follow. I did the following:

1. make a slice by 'tradeDate' and slice it again by 'ticker' then
2. count the changes in q_bool and make it into a new temp_multiindex_df
3. subtract 1 from temp_multiindex_df if df_slice row count is odd
4. add changes_in_qbool to a cumulative_round_trip_count variable, and
5. use for loops to make slices and run through all the dates and tickers in my df.

Problems with my current working solution:

1. double counts if I purchase to hold long-term at the beginning and ending of the day.
2. this solution does not output a summary day trader df.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: can you specify. what is it actually want to do refering to the df

Comment: @sadbro this is a part of a trading engine. The engine must not allow any new "dayTrader" type trades due to United States Regulations if the account value is less than 25,000 and the day_trader_transaction_count is equal to 4.


A day trader transaction is defined as a purchase and a sale of a security within a day. The above question attempts to calculate today's round_trip_transactions aka dayTrader transactions without undercounting and without overcounting. The current solution errs on the side of overcounting. 


The df output is for a dashboard that graphs leverage and algo return

Comment: can you please tell me your intention to do with quantity values(positive or negativer)